# images doesn't show LATEX (overleaf]

Tags: graphics, overleaf

i'm working on an online editor of latex called overleaf , the images doesn't show and o**nly the file name appears**

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\includegraphics{images/orga.png}
\caption{Organigramme}
\label{org} 
\end{figure}
```

PS: i also imported the package : `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Comment: You might have set Overleaf to work in Draft mode. Does https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Images_not_showing_up help?

Comment: i'm using the normal compilation mode already .. and i tried it with texmaker but the same thing happened ..

Comment: Your code fragment works fine. Problem is in not showed part of your document. Please, exend your code frgment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass[...]{...}` and ending with \end{document}` which reproduce your problem. For image instead yours (which we haven't) use `example-image` provided by `graphicx` package.

Comment: Then there must be something in your code that is switching the output into draft mode for graphicx, or there will have been some other error message about the image file. Please construct a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) showing the problem (through this process you may find the problem) so we can see the complete code needed to show the problem. Alternatively, contact us at support@overleaf.com with your project's URL and we can take a look at your entire project. (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.)

Comment: Try the picture file name without extension. i.e. `\includegraphics{images/orga}`